# EF Code-First approach - cannot create SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I would like to emphasize that I'm a beginner with EF. I downloaded and installed SQL Server, then I looked at some tutorials about code-first approach. I've created model classes, and a `ProjectDbContext` class.

I've created this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectDbContext" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Server=LAPTOP\SQLSerwer; Database=Project; Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And an error occurs:

> Cannot open database "ProjectDbContext" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'LAPTOP\user'

I've tried making new project and connecting it in the same way - it worked.

I don't know what completely is happening here, I assume that maybe the first project is not targeting the SQL Server somehow (?).

When I'm running

```
database-update -verbose
```

I see that

> Target database is: 'ProjectDbContext' (DataSource: (localdb)\mssqllocaldb, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention)

which is not the installed SQL Server, right?

First project was created before SQL Server installation

Comment: Your database name is completely wrong (LAPTOP\Sqlswer)

Comment: When i'm connecting via SQL Server Management Studio the 'Server name' in 'Connect to Server' dialog is as I stated (I simplified it by some numbers and letters ex. 93A0-aA).

Comment: there might be a typo in your _ConnectionString_. I mean the _w_ in _Server=LAPTOP\SQLSerwer_. The order of installation does not matter.

Comment: I copied and pasted name from the 'Connect to Server' dialog, so it must be correct :/